# Notes not sounding on barre chords

Tags: fingerstyle-guitar

I have being trying to conquer to barre chord but there when I play then either the d or e strings don't sound. I think I am playing them correctly, using the bony part but one note always doesn't sound out.

How do I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: The D string should be pressed with pinky on E-shape barre chords.

Comment: Sorry I meant barre chords such as f# major

Comment: On the barred second fret using an E-shaped chord, it makes F# major.

Comment: IIRC there are lots of questions about this on the site (search for 'barre') but it often comes down to 1) make sure your guitar is set up properly, with a nice low action at the nut 2) get your hand and elbow position right 3) practice 4) accept that progress might be slow and you may have to find some ways to cheat!

Comment: Practise barre chords on 5,6 or 7 fret, assuming the guitar hasn't a high, bad action.It's usually easier than frets 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fret the barre chord then play each individual string, any one that doesn't play is either not being fretted correctly (not being pressed hard enough, or being pressed too far from the fret, or over the fret) or is being interfered with by another finger.

Either of these scenarios should be simple to spot. If another finger is damping the string you should be able to feel it. If you aren't pressing the string correctly, you just need to work out what the issue is. Try moving the finger, pressing harder etc. See what works for that string.

It is harder than just playing one string, you may need to develop your finger strength and technique, but keep with it.

Answer (score 1):

You must do fingerstyle barre chords exersises every day strumming chords on barre is easy for beginners but fingerstyle need everyday exersises so that you do those with no fear and relaxed motion (iam a classical guitarist ) and those are a must